# How to load a UserControl in WPF with reflection?

Tags: wpf, reflection, user-controls, wpf-controls

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var assm = Assembly.LoadFrom("wpflib.dll");
    foreach (var t in assm.GetTypes())
    {
        var i = t.GetInterface("test.ILib");
        if (i != null)
        {
            var tmp = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(UserControl)) as UserControl;
            this.stackPanel1.Children.Add(tmp);
        }
    }
}
```

tmp(UserControl1 in wpflib.dll) only contains a label and a textbox.

Windows1 (test.exe) reference ILib.dll, and only contains a  stackPanel1.

But, why there is nothong in Windows1(stackPanel1)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not instantiating the type from the DLL at all. Instead of:

```
var tmp = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(UserControl)) as UserControl;
```

write:

```
var tmp = Activator.CreateInstance(t) as UserControl;
```

Furthermore, I would recommend that you actually write

```
var tmp = (UserControl) Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```

instead. Otherwise, if you have a bug, you will get a null-reference exception later on, which is not very informative and hard to debug. This way you get a more meaningful type-cast exception in the right place where the bug actually happens.

Comment: var tmp = Activator.CreateInstance(t) as UserControl;
t is a interface, and can't be created instance. How to do that?

Comment: Change `assm.GetTypes()` to `assm.GetTypes().Where(type => !type.IsInterface)`?

Comment: Sorry, it's my fault.i is a interface,t is the type!