# Is there a way to run main code from user control?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a user control with a button (and more) but I want on click of that to create another instance of that user control in a main window.

Main:

```
UserControl mycontrol1= new UserControl();            
mainwin.Children.Add(mycontrol1);
```

in mycontrol there is a button an on click I'd like to create another mycontrol2 but this does not work

```
UserControl mycontrol2= new UserControl();   
this.Parent.Children.Add(mycontrol2);
this.Parent.FunctionOfMainProgIWantToRUn();
```

I come from ActionScript world and this would run there but WPF logic is hard to get.

Comment: what is the Parent Control Type? is it a Form, Panel, StackPanel,...etc..?

Comment: Also what is the actual name of the UserControl..? that's where you are making a mistake in your code

Comment: @DJKRAZE "mainwin" is the name of the xaml grid where I am attaching mycontrol1

Comment: I am not sure if what I was going to post will work in XAML in windows it would would you like to see an example of what I would do using your code..in Windows what is the name of your UserControl

Comment: `WPF logic is hard to get` - No it's not. It's simpler than anything in existance. The problem is that people don't seem to understand that [UI is Not Data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381402/wpf-programming-methodology/14382137#14382137). Don't know what ActionScript is, but C# is `Statically Typed`, you can't go around calling methods that don't exist. I suggest you research on [MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) if you expect to succeed in WPF. Also, WPF is intended to work with a proper `Architecture` and not just juggling code around here and there.

Comment: @DJKRAZE yes please. But also if my logic here is totally off, please let me know.

Comment: HighCore I am not sure what the post has to do with the original question

Comment: take a look at creating the instance through `Reflection` here is a link that should help you. I do not want to confuse the issue since I am not a WPF guru http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536080/how-to-load-a-usercontrol-in-wpf-with-reflection

Comment: @DJKRAZE Reflection is the last option. When you have to do something that simple with reflection, that's a sign that you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @DavidCol Please post a screenshot of what you need and your current XAML so I can tell you the right way to implement it. Don't use reflection, it's not the right technique for what you need here.

Comment: `MyUserControlName mycontrol2c = new MyUserControlName();
mainwin.Children.Add(mycontrol2);` not sure why this shouldn't work for you.. `REPLACE MyUserControlName` with the actual UserControl not the Type

Comment: @DJKRAZE: You mean the `Type` of the actual `UserControl`, not the base type `UserControl`.

Comment: Yes that's what I am saying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way I can approach your question is:  Using EvenHandler in Usercontrol and subscribing to it in mainView. On each say button click in Usercontrol raise the event.

I just created a sample:

we have textbox and button in Usercontrol

this is code-behind;

```
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> CreateNewUserControl = null;
    public static int InstanceCount = 0;
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(UserControl1_Loaded);
    }

    void UserControl1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        InstanceCount++;
        txtControl.Text = "Control - " + InstanceCount;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var handler = CreateNewUserControl;
        if (handler != null)
         handler.Invoke(sender,e);
    }
}
```

In MainView:

Xaml:

```
   <StackPanel x:Name="UserControlTest" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" MaxHeight="800" Margin="30">

            <RadChartProject:UserControl1 x:Name="UserControl1"/>

        </StackPanel>
```

xaml.cs:

```
      public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        UserControl1.CreateNewUserControl += UserControl1_CreateNewUserControl;
    }

    void UserControl1_CreateNewUserControl(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(UserControlTest != null)
        {
            var control = new UserControl1();
            control.CreateNewUserControl += UserControl1_CreateNewUserControl;
            UserControlTest.Children.Add(control);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! I tested it and it works great. This is exactly what I needed!

Comment: One more thing... I can not figure out how do I know in MainView which button sent the click?

Comment: In my example sender is nothing but a button. var button = (sender as button). now you know which button it is. Best way is assign some unique value to button commandparameter.

Answer (score 0):

You are really doing this the wrong way around. The "right" way would be to have a model class that exposes a collection. You collection should then be bound to an `ItemsControl` (like list view) that then uses a `DataTemplate` to create your `UserControl` for each item in the list and bind it's properties.

The [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) pattern is really worth learning about and makes WPF development much easier to manage and much easier to maintain. It looks like more work up-front, but it's really worth it in the long run.